# Add a Key Listener to TitleAreaDialog

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface, keylistener

I need to add a key listener to my `TitelAreaDialog` is there any solution to do this ?

Comment: To which part of the dialog? What should happen when you press a key?

Comment: The whole dialog. there will be a Barcode scan

Comment: -1, because `this question does not show any research effort`. But welcome to StackOverflow, and I hope you find it useful.

Comment: I'm a beginner in java, i made some search on internet, i found how to add a listener to a control not for the dialog. but thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a `Listener` to the `Display` by using:

```
Listener listener = new Listener() {
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        System.out.println(event.character);
    }
}
getShell().getDisplay().addFilter(SWT.KeyDown, listener);
```

This will output all pressed keys without consuming the events, i.e. the underlying widgets will still register the events.

---

Remember to remove it again in the `close()` method of the `Dialog`:

```
@Override
public boolean close()
{
    getShell().getDisplay().removeFilter(SWT.KeyDown, listener);
    super.close();
}
```

Comment: If I modify something in the dialog and then press ESC key the listener is not called anymore, is there a way to still listen to the ESC key after modification in some controls inside the dialog?