# Adding KeyListener to TitleAreaDialog

Tags: java, swt, jface, keylistener, titleareadialog

I have a `TitleAreaDialog` with a `TableViewer` which allows the user to select a row from the table. The problem is, that the content of the table may change over time. I would like to implement a refresh behaviour commonly found in browsers (e.g. by pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> the content of the table  should refresh).

Below is a screenshot which should hopefully make the scenario a little clearer:

It looks like there is a possible solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12752468/add-a-key-listener-to-titleareadialog), but I think it is flawed for several reasons:

- The listener isn't properly detached (e.g if I reopen my dialog I have two filters on my `Display`)
- It doen't add the listener to the `TitleAreaDialog` or a `Widget` where I believe it belongs from an architectural point of view.
- I would like to avoid manual listener-attaching/detaching (e.g. the listener should get disposed together with the `TitleAreaDialog`)

**Long story short:** What is the proper way of adding a `KeyListener` to a `TitleAreaDialog` (or  `Dialog` in general) without using the filter mechanism as described in the [aforementioned question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12752468/add-a-key-listener-to-titleareadialog)?

I know that this question somehwhat fails in the [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) department, but any pointers into the right direction are highly appreciated.

[image: Dialog with TableViewer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a `Listener` for key events is a tricky thing. You want the `Listener` to be fired when none of the contained `Control`s has focus and you want it to fire even if a child of the `Dialog` has focus.

There are basically two solutions to this problem:

1. The obvious choice: Use `addFilter` when the `Dialog` is created and `removeFilter` when the dialog is closed (in `close()`).
2. Create a `Listener` for `SWT.KeyUp` and add it to *ALL* children of the `Dialog`. This is necessary for the event to fire independent of the focus control.

I prefer solution 1, since it's less clutter and SWT will take care of everything (well, except for adding and removing the filter). Adding a `Listener` to all child controls is nothing you really should do, but it would do the job as well.

---

If you don't want to add and remove the filter each time, create a subclass `Dialog` or `TitleAreaDialog` that does it once, and reuse it by subclassing again.

If adding and removing the filter is too much hassle in general, then I'm afraid there is no easier solution.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I implemented solution 1 and it works as expected.